# WordPress: WooCommerce email_order_items_table remove price

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce

I’m new to PHP and also new to WooCommerce.
I want to edit the [woo-custom-emails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-custom-emails/) plugin.
As a user I have the possibility to set `{email_order_items_table}` in my text which outputs the product name, followed by its quantity, followed by the price. I want to remove the price!

Here is what it does in code:

```
    // file: my_plugin/admin/class-wcemails-instance.php

    $this->find[]    = '{email_order_items_table}';
    $this->replace[] = $this->object->email_order_items_table();
```

here is what the that function does:

```
    // file: woocommerce/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-order.php

/**
 * Output items for display in html emails.
 *
 * @param array $args Items args.
 * @param null $deprecated1 Deprecated arg.
 * @param null $deprecated2 Deprecated arg.
 * @param null $deprecated3 Deprecated arg.
 * @param null $deprecated4 Deprecated arg.
 * @param null $deprecated5 Deprecated arg.
 * @return string
 */
public function email_order_items_table( $args = array(), $deprecated1 = null, $deprecated2 = null, $deprecated3 = null, $deprecated4 = null, $deprecated5 = null ) {
    ob_start();

    if ( ! is_null( $deprecated1 ) || ! is_null( $deprecated2 ) || ! is_null( $deprecated3 ) || ! is_null( $deprecated4 ) || ! is_null( $deprecated5 ) ) {
        _deprecated_argument( __FUNCTION__, '2.5.0' );
    }

    $defaults = array(
        'show_sku'      => false,
        'show_image'    => false,
        'image_size'    => array( 32, 32 ),
        'plain_text'    => false,
        'sent_to_admin' => false
    );

    $args     = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
    $template = $args['plain_text'] ? 'emails/plain/email-order-items.php' : 'emails/email-order-items.php';

    wc_get_template( $template, apply_filters( 'woocommerce_email_order_items_args', array(
        'order'               => $this,
        'items'               => $this->get_items(),
        'show_download_links' => $this->is_download_permitted() && ! $args['sent_to_admin'],
        'show_sku'            => $args['show_sku'],
        'show_purchase_note'  => $this->is_paid() && ! $args['sent_to_admin'],
        'show_image'          => $args['show_image'],
        'image_size'          => $args['image_size'],
        'plain_text'          => $args['plain_text'],
        'sent_to_admin'       => $args['sent_to_admin']
    ) ) );

    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_email_order_items_table', ob_get_clean(), $this );
}
```

and that is the template:

```
    // file: woocommerce/templates/emails/email-order-items.php

<?php
/**
 * Email Order Items
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/email-order-items.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see         https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates/Emails
 * @version     2.1.2
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

foreach ( $items as $item_id => $item ) :
    $_product     = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_product', $order->get_product_from_item( $item ), $item );
    $item_meta    = new WC_Order_Item_Meta( $item, $_product );

    if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_visible', true, $item ) ) {
    ?>
    <tr class="<?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_class', 'order_item', $item, $order ) ); ?>">
        <td class="td" style="text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; border: 1px solid #eee; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; word-wrap:break-word;"><?php

            // Show title/image etc
            if ( $show_image ) {
                echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_thumbnail', '<div style="margin-bottom: 5px"><img src="' . ( $_product->get_image_id() ? current( wp_get_attachment_image_src( $_product->get_image_id(), 'thumbnail') ) : wc_placeholder_img_src() ) .'" alt="' . esc_attr__( 'Product Image', 'woocommerce' ) . '" height="' . esc_attr( $image_size[1] ) . '" width="' . esc_attr( $image_size[0] ) . '" style="vertical-align:middle; margin-right: 10px;" /></div>', $item );
            }

            // Product name
            echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', $item['name'], $item, false );

            // SKU
            if ( $show_sku && is_object( $_product ) && $_product->get_sku() ) {
                echo ' (#' . $_product->get_sku() . ')';
            }

            // allow other plugins to add additional product information here
            do_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_start', $item_id, $item, $order, $plain_text );

            // Variation
            if ( ! empty( $item_meta->meta ) ) {
                echo '<br/><small>' . nl2br( $item_meta->display( true, true, '_', "\n" ) ) . '</small>';
            }

            // File URLs
            if ( $show_download_links ) {
                $order->display_item_downloads( $item );
            }

            // allow other plugins to add additional product information here
            do_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', $item_id, $item, $order, $plain_text );

        ?></td>
        <td class="td" style="text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; border: 1px solid #eee; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;"><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_email_order_item_quantity', $item['qty'], $item ); ?></td>
        <td class="td" style="text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; border: 1px solid #eee; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;"><?php echo $order->get_formatted_line_subtotal( $item ); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}

if ( $show_purchase_note && is_object( $_product ) && ( $purchase_note = get_post_meta( $_product->id, '_purchase_note', true ) ) ) : ?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" style="text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; border: 1px solid #eee; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;"><?php echo wpautop( do_shortcode( wp_kses_post( $purchase_note ) ) ); ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I could replace the template as described in the comments BUT that would overwrite all emails to hide the price and I actually want to keep the price in all other emails that are not send through the plugin. I have no idea on how to make this conditional.

So here is my question: **How can I hook that `email_order_items_table()` function to not output the price?**

*PS: How can I see what is inside `$this->object` or how can I output in a human readable form everything inside the `$this`object?*

Answer (score 1):

In woocommerce all templates can be override if you put it on your theme,
so:

```
woocommerce/templates/emails/email-order-items.php
```

can be override if you put it on:

```
wp-content/themes/{your theme}/woocomerce/{the template}
```

in this case

```
content/themes/{your theme}/woocommerce/emails/email-order-items.php
```

Then you can change the template, so it dont draw the price.

take out this line on the file that is on your themes directory. Be carefull some time you change somthing on the plugin directory and you will lose it on the next update.

```
<td class="td" style="text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; border: 1px solid #eee; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;"><?php echo $order->get_formatted_line_subtotal( $item ); ?></td>
```

br

Answer (score 0):

You can use either of this to see the object printed as an array in human readable form.

```
echo '<pre>';print_r($this->object);exit;
echo '<pre>';print_r($this);exit;
```

Or you may need to log the object into error log file like below

```
error_log(print_r($this->object, 1), true);
```